# dropdown menu like http://www.teslamotors.com/

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, jquery-animate

My clients request is to make their website menu like http://www.teslamotors.com/. So far I have done is the following

HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="main-menu-back" class="short"><!-- Begin: main-menu-back -->
    <div id="main-menu-wrapper">
    <ul id="main-menu">
<li id="about"><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
<li id="service"><a href="service.php">Services</a></li>
<li id="contact"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="logo"><!-- Begin: logo -->
    <h1><a href="index.php"><img src="images/interface/logo_9.jpg" width="90" height="80" alt="img" /></a></h1>
    </div>
<!-- End: logo -->
    </div>
    </div><!-- End: main-menu-back -->
<div id="menu_slider" style="top: -55px;">
<div id="menu_slider_wrapper">
<div id="menu01" class="submenu" style="left: 100px;">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Office and Home Security Systems</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Office and Home Interiors and Electrical Wiring</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Biogas Power Plantations/ Solar Power Plantations</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Vehicle Tracking Devices/ Vehicle Security System</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Fire Alarm and Fire Hydrant Systems/Related Equipment Supply and   Installations</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Ventilation Systems/Related Equipment Supply and Installations</a>    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="menu02" class="submenu" style="left: 300px;">
<ul>
<li><a href="contact.php?type=location">Our Location</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.php?type=contact">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
    <div id="header_bottom">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    #header
    {
    height: 90px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 102;
    }
    #main-menu-back.short {
    background: url(../images/interface/header-top-back-short.JPG) repeat-x;
    height: 59px;
    }
    #main-menu-back
    {
    background: url(../images/interface/header-top-back.JPG) repeat-x scroll center top         #DDDDDD;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 8px 1px #6D6B6B;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    height: 90px;
    min-width: 960px;
    position: absolute;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
    }
    #main-menu-back.short #main-menu-wrapper {
    height: 62px;
    height: 62px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    }
    #logo{
    display: inline;
    width: 78px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 825px;
    z-index: 4 !important;
    }
    #logo h1 a img{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    }
    #header_bottom
    {
    background: url(../images/interface/header-bottom-back.png) repeat-x;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.60);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.60);
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.60);
    position: absolute;
    top: 59px;
    }
    ul#main-menu
    {
    margin:0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    }

    ul#main-menu li
    { padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 2px 70px 0 0;
    display: inline;
    background: transparent;
    }

    ul#main-menu li a
    {
    color: #707070;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
    }

    ul#main-menu li:hover a
    {
    color: #B80007;
    }
    #menu_slider
    {
    background: url(../images/interface/submenu-back.JPG) repeat-x;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 111px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 8px 1px #6D6B6B;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 2 !IMPORTANT;
    }
    #menu_slider_wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    }
    #menu_slider div.submenu
    {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    }
    #menu_slider div.submenu ul {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    min-width: 140px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    }
    #menu_slider div.submenu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    }
    #menu_slider div.submenu li a {
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    }
```

JS

```
        $("ul#main-menu li").mouseenter(function () {
            var hoverCntrlId = $(this).attr("id");
            console.log(hoverCntrlId);
            if (hoverCntrlId == "contact") {
                $("div#menu01").hide();
                $("div#menu02").show();
            } else if (hoverCntrlId == "service") {
                $("div#menu01").show();
                $("div#menu02").hide();
            }

            $('#menu_slider').animate({
                top: '61px'
            }, 1000, function () {
                $('#menu_slider').slideDown(1000);

            });
        });
        $('ul#main-menu li, #menu_slider').mouseleave(function () {
            var hoverCntrlId = $(this).attr("id");
            var msPosition = $("#menu_slider").attr("top");
            if (msPosition == "61px") {
                $('#menu_slider').stop().animate({
                    top: '-55px'
                });
            }

            if (hoverCntrlId == "menu_slider") {
                $('#menu_slider').stop();
                $('#menu_slider').animate({
                    top: '-55px'
                }, 1000, function () {
                    $('#menu_slider').slideUp(1000);
                });
            }
        });
```

I am able to slide up and down the div containing submenu but animation problem occurs my mouse leaves menu_slider and enters #main-menu li, then the animation occurs twice.
I am not able resolve the problem. Can anyone help.

Comment: I don't see their dropdown menu on the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using both an animation of the top property and the jQ `slideDown` function, you should only use one of them. Both have the affect of animating in the menu (the slideDown function animates the menu's *height* and the animation of the `top` property is affecting the menu's *position*).

Tesla only use the top property and I recommend you do the same. Simply remove the callbacks with the slideDown/slideUp animations.

For example:

```
$('#menu_slider').animate({
    top: '61px'
}, 1000, function () {
    $('#menu_slider').slideDown(1000);
});
```

Should simply become:

```
$('#menu_slider').animate({
    top: '61px'
}, 1000);
```

I'd also recommend you store the current state of the slide-menu in a boolean and test for it when animating. something like this:

```
var showing = false;
function showslideout(){
    if(!showing){
        showing = true;
        //code to show the menu here
    }
}
function hideslideout(){
    if(showing){
        showing = false;
        //code to hide the menu here
    }
}
```

Notice how the boolean is changed before the animation. This means that if showslideout was called once and then again before the first had finished, the animation would only occur once.

As a side note, be careful about using explicit heights. This will make the site difficult to maintain if you, for example, wanted to change the height of the main navigation bar. Tesla gets the height of the main navigation bar dynamically will jQ. They store two values that can be assigned to the `top` property of the slideNav to either hide or show it:

```
var hideY =- $slideNav.height() + $("#main-nav-back").height()-5;
var showY = $("#main-nav-back").height();
```

Hope this helps!